# How to declare variables scrollTop

Tags: jquery

I have this function.

```
$(".link").click(function(){
            var page = $(this).attr("id");
            var color = $(this).attr("class");
            var height = $(this).attr("class");
            var scrolltop = 100;
            color = color.substr(5,6);
            height = height.substr(12,6);
            $('#all_pages').animate({left: (page-1)*(-650) }); 
            $("body").animate({backgroundColor: '#'+color});
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrolltop}, 'slow');
            $("#container").animate({height: height});
            $("#all_pages").animate({height: height});
            $("#menu ul li").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active'); 
        });
```

and these links:

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li id="1" class="link 99CCCC 0620px 0000px active">Home</li>
                <li id="2" class="link FF9933 0890px 0200px">Services</li>
                <li id="3" class="link 66FFCC 1265px 0210px">Tourism</li>
                <li id="4" class="link 99FF99 1580px 0220px">Prices</li>
                <li id="5" class="link FF9999 0485px 0230px">Ask question</li>
                <li id="6" class="link 00CCFF 0450px 0240px">Partners</li>
                <li id="7" class="link EBF291 0450px 0250px">FAQ</li>   
                <li id="8" class="link FFFF66 0850px 0260px">Contact Us</li>                            
            </ul>
        </div>
```

From the links I get the color of the background, the height of the page.
I also want to get information on the position on the page, but I can not figure out how to get the value of the variable --- `var scrolltop`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Look into data attributes. These are much better than class substrings.

Comment: since you're setting a hard value to scrollTop anyways, why not just do scrollTop: 100?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data-*` attribute to hold the values of your custom attributes.

Use

```
<li data-page="1" data-color="99CCCC" data-height="620" data-position="0" class="link active">Home</li>
```

instead of

```
<li id="1" class="link 99CCCC 0620px 0000px active">Home</li>
```

Use `.data()` to get the properties from JavaScript.

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    /* cache the selector */
    var $this = $(this);
    /* Get the properties */
    var page = $this.data("page");
    var color = $this.data("color");
    var height = $this.data("height");
    /* I suppose this is what you wanted */
    var scrolltop = $this.data("position");
    ...
});​
```

---

If by clicking in each `<li>` is supposed to scroll the viewport to a certain position in the page where another element resides. Then you could get the position of that element and scroll there instead of hardcoding the values.

For example,

You want to scroll to an element with `id` set to `home`.

```
<div id="home">
```

Set the `data-position` attribute to the selector for it, `#home`.

```
<li data-page="1" data-color="99CCCC" data-height="620" data-position="#home" class="link active">Home</li>
```

Get the element using the selector, get the position of it using [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and scroll to it.

```
var $target = $($this.data("position"));
var scrolltop = $target.offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: scrolltop }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position ,
by using this code

```
$(this).offset().top;
```

you can find more about this function on this link

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

I hope this could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

In the sole case you're not able to change the HTML result:
use `.split(' ')` to retrieve data from attr class and you don't need 'px' and leading *zeros* so use `parseInt`.

### [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ewiweb/1/edit)

```
$(".link").click(function(){
  
  var myClass   = $(this).attr("class").split(' '); // split class
  var color     = myClass[1];
  var height    = parseInt( myClass[2] , 10);
  var scrolltop = parseInt( myClass[3] , 10); 
  
  alert( color+' '+height+' '+scrolltop );
  
});
```

In all other cases use the `.data()` attribute as suggested by @Alexander

Comment: "but look, there is something better than a split class"

Comment: lol @JanDvorak please find me an article that says that you should not split a class to retrieve class names -> and that it's slower or not better than to use `data` for THIS SPECIFIC case.

Comment: @Jan the demo I posted is exactly what the OP needs to do, and WE don't know if the OP is able to change the HTML result to apply your *magic* data attributes.

Comment: There's no magic in data attributes, you know that. Chill out

Comment: @Alexander the chill is inappropriate as long as helpful answers are being downvoted. You know that

Comment: @roXon I've never downvoted the answer and I don't know why it was downvoted. There's nothing bad in splitting a class attribute by space (except there's no need for that). Storing data in the class attribute can be done without (as the other answer shows), so I won't upvote.

Comment: Update: I _will_ upvote since it might be the case the HTML cannot be changed (you should still prepend "you could" to your answer).

Comment: @Jan I'm not here to be upvoted/downvoted, but to teach and learn. So you're right, I added the missing quote. thx